# Fix PL/SQL program that sends e-mail

Tags: oracle, plsql, smtp, sendgrid

The following PL/SQL program that sends email, which uses basic authentication to authenticate to sendgrid, was working until yesterday.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE ENVIA_EMAIL(        p_remetente             IN VARCHAR2
                                        ,p_destinatario          IN VARCHAR2
                                        ,p_titulo_email          IN VARCHAR2
                                        ,p_mensagem              IN VARCHAR2
                                        ,p_dsc_arquivo_atachado1 IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL
                                        ,p_tipo_arquivo1         IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'TEXT'
                                        ,p_dsc_arquivo_atachado2 IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL
                                        ,p_tipo_arquivo2         IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'TEXT'
                                        ,p_dsc_arquivo_atachado3 IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL
                                        ,p_tipo_arquivo3         IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'TEXT'
                                        ,p_username              IN VARCHAR2
                                        ,p_password              IN VARCHAR2) IS
 --

   -- Declaracao de variaveis
   w_usuario           NUMBER(10);
   w_smtp_ip           VARCHAR2(30)           := 'smtp.sendgrid.net';
   w_smtp_porta        NUMBER                 := 587;
   boundary            CONSTANT VARCHAR2(256) := 'CES.Boundary.DACA587499938897';
   w_conexao           UTL_SMTP.CONNECTION;
   w_mensagem          VARCHAR2(30000);
   w_nova_linha        VARCHAR(2)             := chr(13)||chr(10);
   wrk_local           NUMBER;
   w_destinatario      VARCHAR2(500);
   w_destinatario_todo VARCHAR2(500);
   w_destin_todo_fixo  VARCHAR2(500);


   TYPE varchar2_table IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(256) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

   w_contador         BINARY_INTEGER;

  function subject_encode(s_string varchar2) return varchar2 is

    temp_subject varchar2(6000);
    lengthsubject pls_integer:= 40;
    w_nova_linha        VARCHAR(2)             := chr(13)||chr(10);
    count_length  pls_integer;
  begin
     count_length:=CEIL(LENGTH(s_string)/lengthsubject);
     temp_subject:='=?iso-8859-1?B?' ||
     utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(utl_encode.base64_encode(utl_raw.cast_to_raw(substr(s_string,1,lengthsubject ))))|| '?=';
     for i in 2..count_length loop
     temp_subject:=temp_subject||'=?iso-8859-1?B?'||
     utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(utl_encode.base64_encode(utl_raw.cast_to_raw( SUBSTR(s_string,1+(lengthsubject*(i-1)) ,lengthsubject ))))|| '?=';
     end loop;
     return temp_subject;
  end;



BEGIN
  w_destinatario_todo := p_destinatario||';';
  w_destin_todo_fixo  := p_destinatario;

  LOOP
    w_destinatario := substr(w_destinatario_todo,1,(instr(w_destinatario_todo,';')) - 1);
    w_destinatario_todo := substr(w_destinatario_todo,(instr(w_destinatario_todo,';') + 1));

    IF w_destinatario IS NOT NULL THEN

      -- Abrindo Conexao SMTP e HTTP
      w_conexao := utl_smtp.open_connection(w_smtp_ip,w_smtp_porta);

      -- Comunicando SMTP
      utl_smtp.helo(w_conexao, w_smtp_ip);

      -- Autenticacao INICIO
      utl_smtp.command(w_conexao,'AUTH LOGIN');
      utl_smtp.command(w_conexao,utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(utl_encode.base64_encode(utl_raw.cast_to_raw(('username')))));
      utl_smtp.command(w_conexao,utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(utl_encode.base64_encode(utl_raw.cast_to_raw(('password')))));
      utl_smtp.mail(w_conexao,('<'||'myusername@myhost.com.br'||'>'));
      utl_smtp.rcpt(w_conexao,('<'||w_destinatario||'>'));
      utl_smtp.open_data (w_conexao);

      -- Criando Cabeca do E-mail
      w_mensagem := 'Date: '||TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'dd Mon yy hh24:mi:ss')||w_nova_linha||
                   'From: '||p_remetente||w_nova_linha||
                   'To: '||w_destin_todo_fixo||w_nova_linha||
                   'Subject: '||subject_encode(p_titulo_email)||w_nova_linha;
---                   'To: '||w_destin_todo_fixo||w_nova_linha;

  --     w_mensagem := w_mensagem || 'Mime-Version: 1.0' || w_nova_linha ||
  --               'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="' || boundary || '"' || w_nova_linha || w_nova_linha; --||

        utl_smtp.write_data(w_conexao,w_mensagem);
      --
      IF p_mensagem IS not NULL THEN
        w_mensagem :=  '--' || boundary || w_nova_linha ||
                     'Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' || w_nova_linha ||
                     'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64' || w_nova_linha || w_nova_linha;

           utl_smtp.write_data(w_conexao,w_mensagem);

           utl_smtp.write_data(w_conexao,utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(utl_encode.base64_encode(utl_raw.cast_to_raw(p_mensagem)))|| w_nova_linha);
       END IF;



      -- Append the final boundary line
 --    w_mensagem := w_nova_linha || '--' || boundary || '--' || w_nova_linha;
 --    utl_smtp.write_data(w_conexao,w_mensagem);

      -- Fechando conexao SMTP
      utl_smtp.close_data(w_conexao);
      utl_smtp.quit(w_conexao);

      -- Insere um registro de emails.
      BEGIN
        w_usuario  :=  substr(USER,2,50);
      EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
          w_usuario  :=  0;
      END;

    END IF;


    IF w_destinatario_todo IS NULL THEN
      EXIT;
    END IF;

  END LOOP;

END;
```

Yesterday sendgrid stopped supporting basic authentication. Now sendgrid require that an api key is used to authenticate.

I followed sendgrid instructions and created an api key via UI portal. Also, I replaced the username and password in the e-mail program with the values of "apikey"(username) and "actualKey"(password) according to sendgrid documentation as illustrated below.

```
utl_smtp.command(w_conexao,utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(utl_encode.base64_encode(utl_raw.cast_to_raw(('apikey')))));
utl_smtp.command(w_conexao,utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(utl_encode.base64_encode(utl_raw.cast_to_raw(('Sdyg.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')))));
```

However, I am getting the following error when attempting to send an e-mail.

"The provided authorization grant is invalid, expired or revoked"

Any advice on how I could fix that?

Comment: You will probably get better answers asking sendgrid support.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that a line break is added when the following is executed

```
select utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(utl_encode.base64_encode(utl_raw.cast_to_raw(('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')))) from dual;
```

the output is

```
U0cuNkU5TExrMHNUamZ0YzZxbG04ZXpnUS5raXhJd2RTSWV0RGE4d0ZUYnNNZHFf
Z1hWeVgxM3dtSHhGdlU5SHZmOTlv
```

To remove that line break, I modified that statement to look like that

```
select replace(replace(replace(utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(utl_encode.base64_encode(utl_raw.cast_to_raw(('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')))),chr(10),' '),chr(13),' '),' ','') from dual;
```

the output is

```
U0cuNkU5TExrMHNUamZ0YzZxbG04ZXpnUS5raXhJd2RTSWV0RGE4d0ZUYnNNZHFfZ1hWeVgxM3dtSHhGdlU5SHZmOTlv
```

Comment: This was my problem too, thanks for posting this.  BTW, you can eliminate the last replace call by just replacing the CR and LF straight to null like this: replace(replace(string,chr(10),''),chr(13),'')